# Refracted rays and reflected rays intensity change

Tags: optics, refraction

When light enters medium A to medium B some light is refracted while some reflected.

How we can derive their relative brightness?

Comment: Let the incident brightness at the first interface be $1$ and the reflected brightness at that interface be $x$ so the transmitted brightness is $1-x$ and you can repeat the proportions at the next two interfaces.  The **order** of brightness for interfaces $2$ and $3$ does not change with $x$ but the **order** of brightness for interfaces $1$ and $2$ does change when $x\approx 0.38$. A figure of $x=0.04$ is often used for an air-glass interface for **normal** incidence as the angle of incidence increases. It is a poor question.

Comment: @Farcher Thanks. However, how can the x be determined?

Comment: Theoretically one would [use the Fresnel equations](http://www1.udel.edu/chem/sneal/sln_tchng/CHEM620/CHEM620/Chi_4._Light_at_Interfaces.html).